# Android service stopself method to change button state

Tags: android, service

I have two buttons -start and stop service buttons- in the fragment. In the initial state start button is enabled and stop button is disabled. When i click "start button",buttons states are changed. -It means start button is disabled and stop button is enabled.  In the service i check gps state. If the gps is disabled, i call stopself method to destroy service. After calling stopself method, I wanna change buttons states in the fragment. But i didn't find any solution. How can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use below option.

**In your fragment.**

```
//In your on Create method 
IntentFilter updateState = new IntentFilter();
updateState.addAction("UPDATE_BUTTON_STATE");
registerReceiver(updateStatueReceiver, updateState);


    private BroadcastReceiver updateStatueReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals("UPDATE_BUTTON_STATE")) {
                // Here you can update your button state
            }
        }
    };

//unregister Receiver in on Destroy method 
unregisterReceiver(updateStatueReceiver);
```

**In your Service Class**

You can send broadcast using this code

```
Intent broadCastIntent = new Intent();
broadCastIntent.setAction("UPDATE_BUTTON_STATE");
sendBroadcast(broadCastIntent);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It works perfectly. I found my mistakes: I forgot to add action to my filter and created intent  on "onDestroy" method.